# Unable to run go build with flags from a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, go

I'm running go 1.8.3 and I have this command in a shell script:

```
go build -gcflags='-N -l'
```

I haven't been able to fix this with quoting, double quoting, escaping quotes, etc in my script. However, if have something like this in my script:

```
gc_flags="-gcflags='-N -l'"
echo go build "${gc_flags}"
go build "${gc_flags}"
```

But if I literally copy and paste the echo output in my console and run it, it works fine.

This is the error I get from my script:

```
flag provided but not defined: -N -l
```

Any help is appreciated here. . . I don't recall ever having an issue like this with a build script before.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you have literal single quotes embedded in the value of the variable.
The shell will not evaluate these embedded single quotes later when using this value.

When you run this:

```
go build -gcflags='-N -l'
```

The shell passes to the `go` command these values as command line arguments:

- `build`
- `-gcflags=-N -l`

When you run this:

```
gc_flags="-gcflags='-N -l'"
go build "${gc_flags}"
```

The shell passes to the `go` command these values as command line arguments:

- `build`
- `-gcflags='-N -l'`

In the first case the single-quotes are not part of the second argument,
because the shell replaces the single-quoted expression `'-N -l'` with the unquoted value `-N -l`.

In the second case no such replacement occurs,
because the content of the variable, containing the single-quotes,
is not reevaluated,
and so the single-quotes remain as part of the second argument.

One way to fix this is to store in the `gc_flags` variable only the flags, without the `-gcflags=`

```
gc_flags='-N -l'
go build -gcflags="$gc_flags"
```

This will have the desired effect,
because the value of `gc_flags` here doesn't contain the single-quotes,
they are removed when evaluating the expression `gc_flags='-N -l'`.

Another way is to use Bash arrays:

```
gc_flags=(-gcflags='-N -l')
go build "${gc_flags[@]}"
```

In this form,
the array has one value, `-gcflags=-N -l`,
the embedded single-quotes have been removed when evaluating the array assignment.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite correct -- the problem is that the shell parses quotes before it expands variable references, so putting quotes in a variable's value doesn't do anything useful -- by the time they're part of the command, it's too late for them to function as quotes. This is true whether or not the variable reference is in double-quotes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson although it could have been phrased more generally, I don't think it was incorrect. Anyway, thanks, I rephrased it a bit, I hope it's better, let me know if you still see room for improvement. This is a common issue, but I find it tricky to explain in a simple, accessible way.

Comment: Ok, I agree with your rephrase. (And I also agree that this is tricky to explain.)

Answer (score 2):

You can see GOGCFLAGS used in a bash scripts [in this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/fb4e185a99f3e93bc1bbe08a09ebfd5419409d48):

```
time go test std -short -timeout=$(expr 120 \* $timeout_scale)s -gcflags "$GO_GCFLAGS"
```

Which means you [only set the values in `GO_GCFLAGS`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8725#issuecomment-66098697).

```
GO_GCFLAGS="-N -l"
```

The OP confirms this is working:

```
gc=-gcflags gc_flags="-N -l" go build "${gc}" "${gc_flags}"
```

Comment: Thanks VonC!  Reading your comment, I tried this:

    gc=-gcflags
    gc_flags="-N -l"
    go build "${gc}" "${gc_flags}"

. . . and it works, which is great.  But I still don't understand why my command above didn't work.

Comment: @matthewcummings516 probably becasue of the way the shell replace the single quotes, as janos explain in his answer.